# How can I replace a substring in a string?

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to write a program to change character if ch is found inside the string called st i will replace it with '!'

I wrote a program but for some reason this code can't replace one letter for example if i enter:
st = a
ch = a

I dont get an output of '!' instead i get 'a' but i dont want that i want it to be '!'

my code is

```
st = raw_input("String: ")
ch = raw_input("character: ")


def replace_char(st,ch):
    if st.find(ch):
        new = st.replace(ch,'!')
        print new
        return new
    elif len(st)==len(ch):
        if ch==st:
            print"!"
        else:
            print st
    else:
        print st
        return st

replace_char(st,ch)
```

Please help i dont get what i'm doing wrong or missing from my code

Comment: Use a reasonable subject -> Downvote.

Comment: str.find() does not return True or False, it returns the index of the found string.

Comment: sorry that was the old one i changed it but still it wont work....

Comment: You are not reading answers

Comment: I am reading your comment, i got rid of the True part and now it should work better but it doesn't work properly

Comment: You are *NOT* reading. I clearly you told you that find() returns the index and NOT true or false. So where is your check for return value -1 ?

Answer (score 3):

From the Python documentation:

> ```
> find(s, sub[, start[, end]])¶
>
> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such 
> that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
> Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
> the same as for slices.
> ```

It does not say anything about find() returning True or False. This is your problem.

For a substring search better use

```
if some_string in some_otherstring:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 2):

st.find(ch) returns position where ch is in st not True/False. Because if  == True is True in Python your program works in some cases... :)
Consider str == 'a' and ch == 'a', first condition fails, but second condition works only if str and ch has same length. I guess u have something else in your st or ch.
In my PC your program works except the case if searching ch is first in st, like following: st = 'afsdf' ch = 'a'.
Better solution is like follows:

```
st.replace(ch, '!')
```

It will work in all cases.